# Android ndk-build can't find glm headers

Tags: android, ndk, glm

I am trying to port some boilerplate code of mine to work on android, using the android ndk & NativeActivity

So far I have just one file that defines the glue between android and my code and it works fine. It includes one GLIncludes file, that sorts out the includes based on platform

However, if I add glm headers to the GLIncludes file, becoming:

```
#ifdef __ANDROID_API__
    #include <EGL/egl.h>
    #include <GLES/gl.h>
    #include <GLES/glext.h>
#endif

#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp"
```

ndk-build then complains about not finding glm.hpp:

```
In file included from jni/src/GLIncludes.h:41:0,
                 from jni/androidLauncher.cpp:4:
jni/src/glm/glm.hpp:86:18: fatal error: limits: No such file or directory
```

I have verified that the file does indeed lie at **< ANDROID_PROJECT_ROOT >/jni/src/glm/glm.hpp** so what could be the problem?

Here is my **Android.mk** file that sits in the jni folder:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libglobes
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv1_CM -lEGL -lm -landroid
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := androidLauncher.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

My directory structure is:

```
< ROOT >
    src/ (dir with all sources in it)
        GLIncludes.h
        glm/
            glm.hpp
    android/ (base dir for android port)
        jni/
            androidLauncher.cpp
            Android.mk
            src/ (symbolic link to upper src folder with same contents)
```

So why is the ndk-build not seeing the glm.hpp files? Is it because it is too deep? or is it because of the symbolic link? Or is it something else completely?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the error message more carefully:

```
In file included from jni/src/GLIncludes.h:41:0,
                 from jni/androidLauncher.cpp:4:
jni/src/glm/glm.hpp:86:18: fatal error: limits: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, the `glm.hpp` header **is** found. It's `limits` that is not found, because by default the NDK uses a stripped-down C++ runtime library.

You will need to read `CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html` to choose what kind of runtime is best for you. In the meantime, adding this to `Application.mk` will probably work:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Comment: AH! Thanks a lot mate Will try that when I'm at my build machine